# How to run php file for only 10 times a day without cron?

Tags: php, datetime, file-handling

I am new to php so please mind if it easy question. I have a php script, I want it to be executed only 10 times a day and not more than that. I don't want to use cron for this. Is there any way to do this in php only?

Right now I have set a counter which increases by one every time any one runs the script and loop it to 10 times only. if it exceeds it it shows an error message.

```
function limit_run_times(){
    $counter = 1;
    $file = 'counter.txt';
    if(file_exists($file)){
         $counter += file_get_contents($file);
    }
    file_put_contents($file,$counter);
    if($counter > 11 ){
        die("limit is exceeded!");
    }
}
```

I want some efficient way to do this so everyday the script is only executed for 10 times and this is applicable for everyday i.e this counter gets refreshed to 0 everyday or is there any other efficient method.

Comment: Look at your code and go through it as the computer would, and see what happens. What you might want to consider if you want to use this code is to pass $counter as a parameter, because settings it to 0 when the function starts is problematic.

Comment: I could write to a file and increment there. but I don't understand how to refresh it back to 0 everyday.

Comment: You could write a file with 2 lines. The first line is a date and the second line is a counter. Then, when you read the file, if it's not the current date, set counter to zero.

Comment: Or you could use a database instead, insert rows into the table with the date. Make a check that there cannot be more than 10 entries of the same date.

Comment: I don't want to use database. I would use file and increment value by 1 till 10 and each day refresh back it to 0.

Comment: Once your file operations are done, you can use windows schedular to run the script. you need to know how to run php on command line.

Comment: @MangeshSathe i must have missed the part where OP mentionned windoze.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a database though, is there any particular reason? IMO, using SQL is better and easier than handling files.

Comment: In any case, do you intend for the script to be run manually or automatically? You've only set a requirement of 10 times a day, but *how* would it execute?

Comment: It can be executed by anyone. But limit of its execution is only 10 times. If it is already called 10 times then it should show the message.

Comment: Then there's no need for a scheduler of any kind, you just need the check before the execution of the rest of the script. If you for whichever reason don't want to use a database (which I would recommend, using a database), then create a file to log it with. Store the timestamp and the counter separated by a tab, then you can retrieve it in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather recommend that you use a database instead - its cleaner and more simple to maintain.

However, it is achievable with file-handling as well. The file will be of format `2019-05-15    1` (separated by tab, `\t`). Fetch the contents of the file and split the values by `explode()`. Then do your comparisons and checks, and return values accordingly.

```php
function limit_run_times() {
    // Variable declarations
    $fileName = 'my_log.txt';
    $dailyLimit = 10;
    $content = file_get_contents($fileName);
    $parts = explode("\t", $content);
    $date = $parts[0];
    $counter = $parts[1] + 1;

    // Check the counter - if its higher than 10 on this date, return false
    if ($counter > $dailyLimit && date("Y-m-d") === $date) {
        die("Daily executing limit ($dailyLimit) exceeded! Please try again tomorrow.");
    }

    // We only get here if the count is $dailyLimit or less
    // Check if the date is today, if so increment the counter by 1
    // Else set the new date and reset the counter to 1 (as it is executed now)
    if (date("Y-m-d") !== $date) {
        $counter = 1;
        $date = date("Y-m-d");
    }
    file_put_contents($fileName, $date."\t".$counter);
    return true;
}
```